# sudo asks for root password but expects user in sudoers?

Tags: password, sudo, root

I have the root account enabled. I have degraded the user (say kenneth) to a standard account and I have set the `Defaults rootpw` flag in sudoers.

When I use sudo it correctly prompt for root password, but then it returns

`kenneth is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`

I'm asking this question here (AskUbuntu) because I have 3 other Linux systems and the same problem doesn't occur there. Is there any difference(any significant change that apply only on Ubuntu) that I have to know or I'm missing something else ?

**sudoers file**

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    rootpw
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
#%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

**groups kenneth**

```
kenneth : kenneth cdrom dip adm plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxusers
```

**groups root**

```
root : root sudo
```

Comment: Funny thing now is, even when I upgrade `kenneth` to administrator (add him to sudo group) the same problem persist. I cannot use `sudo` with kenneth's password (tried of course with `Defaults rootpw` commented out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding was that `rootpw` just changes the behaviour of the password prompt. Your users still need to be named (explicitly, or through groups) `/etc/sudoers`.

In this case `kenneth` isn't. Fix that and this should work.

---

On a side note, this seems like a really backwards use of `sudo`. This is exactly the sort of behaviour `sudo` was invented to prevent against. You might as well just `su`.

Comment: Something wrecked here Oli, but I don't know what. As I have commented at my own question, even when I restore the user (as an admin - by adding him to sudo group) sudo refuses to run properly. I have now added a new user (say john) just to test, and there everything works. (Defaults rootpw and the like).

Comment: In the case where you're adding the user to the right group, are you logging out and in again? That's required for a user to pick up group changes.

Comment: I have added and removed 3 comments at the last 10-15 minutes. But I think this is the final. 
Here is the deal. If the user `kenneth` don't belong to sudo group, the `sudo` command doesn't work properly with the `rootpw` flag on. Additionally you have to logout (completely - login shell also) in order for changes to take effect. That's it.

Comment: @Oli  *`newgrp(1)`* should also work though.